# When is $u_1 = w_1 + aw_2, u_2 = w_2 + a w_1$ a basis if $w_1, w_2$ is a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

If $V$ is a $2$-dimensional $K$-vector space with basis $w_1, w_2$, when is
$$
 u_1 := w_1 + a w_2 \qquad
 u_2 := w_2 + a w_1 
$$
is basis. Of course for $a = 1$ it is certainly not, but how could this restricted further?

Comment: Consider the determinant of the transformation matrix.

Comment: Yes, then it gives $1-a^2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow a^2 = 1 \Leftrightarrow a = \pm 1$ for characteristic $\ne 2$, and $a = 1$ otherwise. But is there an approach without coordinates?

Comment: Why would you think that proving a particular coordinate system is a basis could be done without coordinates?

Comment: Maybe just deriving from $\alpha u_1 + \beta u_2 = 0$ that $\alpha = \beta = 0$ directly using vector space and field axioms?

Comment: Sure, but to make any headway you rewrite $u_1$ and $u_2$ in terms of $w_1$ and $w_2$, and use the fact that it's a basis. This is still 'using coordinates'.

Comment: What you mean? If I go $0 = \alpha u_1 + \beta u_2 = (\alpha + \beta)w_1 + a(\alpha + \beta)w_2$, which gives as $w_1, w_2$ is a basis $\alpha + \beta = 0$ and $a(\alpha + \beta) = 0$. If $a \ne 0$ this gives the single equation $\alpha + \beta = 0$, from which I see no way to derive $\alpha = \beta = 0$.

Comment: Oops. I see my error! Okay, yes this is also like computing with coordinates then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T:V \to V$ be the unique endomorphism such that $T(w_1) = u_1$ and $T(w_2) = u_2$. Then $T$ maps a basis to a basis iff $T$ is an automorphism, i.e., it is invertible. The matrix of $T$ in the basis $(w_1,w_2)$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a\\
a & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

You can conclude from there.